# what's the difference of strong ordered architecture and poorly ordered architecture

Tags: cpu-architecture, memory-barriers

We known that X86_64 is a strongly ordered architecture. On the contrary, ARM64 or PowerPC or ... Alpha are poorly ordered ones.

What's the difference between them? Does this infulence the process schedule? Will it make executable program more unpredictable if architecture is poorly ordered?

Comment: What use would an unpredictable program be?

Comment: Not unpredictable program,  the unpredictable is out-of-order.

Comment: No, this refers to the memory ordering model adopted by a processor architecture. With some Google-fu one lands here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering

Comment: We prefer the term weakly-ordered :) I'll be lazy enough to link to an old  answer of mine with a fair amount of overlap with what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491751/real-life-use-cases-of-barriers-dsb-dmb-isb-in-arm/15493922#15493922

Comment: Oh, and on-topic, the documentation in the Linux kernel is also a quite good primer: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Comment: @unixsmurf thanks for your reply:)