# Which ARM memory barrier guarantees that one of two threads will observe what the other thread wrote?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, arm, memory-barriers, memory-visibility

Threads A and B are executing concurrently. Which ARMv8-A memory barrier types (like DMB, DSB) are sufficient to fulfill the postcondition, and why?

```
Initially x1 = 0, x2 = 0


Thread A         |   Thread B
----------------------------------
x1 = 1           |   x2 = 1
barrier          |   barrier
y1 = x2          |   y2 = x1


Postcondition: (y1 == 1) || (y2 == 1)
```

---

I looked at the [ARMv8-A Architecture Reference Manual memory model definition of DMB and DSB](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0487/ea/DDI0487E_a_armv8_arm.pdf#G9.11240882), but could not deduce an argument why the postcondition would hold even with the DSB memory barrier. I think the key definitions in the Architecture Reference Manual are:

> The DMB instruction ensures that all affected memory accesses by the PE executing the DMB that appear in program order before the DMB and those which originate from a different PE [...] which have been Observed-by the PE before the DMB is executed, are Observed-by each PE [...] before any affected memory accesses that appear in program order after the DMB are Observed-by that PE.

and

> A DSB executed by a PE [...] completes when all of the following apply:
>
> - All explicit memory accesses of the required access types appearing in program order before the DSB are complete for the set of observers in the required shareability domain.
> - [...]

and

> In addition, no instruction that appears in program order after the DSB instruction can alter any state of the system or perform any part of its functionality until the DSB completes other than [...]

Comment: I would write it in C/C++ model then use a [recommended translation](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html); it says "SeqCst Fence: `dmb ish`"

Comment: same core or different cores?  did you look at strex/ldrex?

Answer (score 1):

[Unix smurf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563188/unixsmurf) wrote a series on [ARM memory barriers](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/memory-access-ordering---an-introduction).  The `DSB` is a super-set of the `DMB` or in other words the `DSB` is more restrictive.  The `DMB` is sufficient to ensure that the writes to `x1` and `x2` are complete before `y1` or `y2` is updated using normal memory.  Ie, it is a sufficient substitute for *barrier* in your example on most ARM systems with `DSB` also working.

---

An OS can use different properties in the MMU tables and this could affect your results.  For instance using graphics RAM or some network devices buffer as the backing store for `x1`, `x2`, may not need to issue a `dmb` or the `dmb` may need different parameters as these type of memory maybe put in a different domain.

In fact, an OS can probably completely subvert these mechanisms.  This won't be a factor for most use cases and I just state it to be complete.  It is also possible to have AMP (asymmetric multi-processor) systems where this won't work.  If you have a system with a ARMv8 and a Cortex-M for instance.

Reference:

- [Real life use cases of dsb, dmb and isb on ARM CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491751/real-life-use-cases-of-barriers-dsb-dmb-isb-in-arm)
- [Barrier Litmus Tests and Cookbook for ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.genc007826/Barrier_Litmus_Tests_and_Cookbook_A08.pdf)

Comment: `ldrex` and `strex` can also work.  `DMB` is the *lightest* version and if one works, they all should.