Assembly "nop" delays in C code have inconsistent timing on nrf9160 (Arm) in Zephyr
I'm trying to modify this bit-banging ws2812 gpio Zephy driver to run on an nrf9160 (Arm Cortex M33) board. The problem is I can't mange to get consistent pulse timing using assembly instructions at the beginning of the transfer.

You can see that the first pulse has about double the width (time) as the second pulse, even though they should be the same (a zero bit).  The 7th and 8th pulse should also be the same (a one bit).
This is the relevant code I've been messing with/debugging:
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2018 Intel Corporation
 * Copyright (c) 2019 Nordic Semiconductor ASA
 * Copyright (c) 2021 Seagate Technology LLC
 *
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
#define DT_DRV_COMPAT worldsemi_ws2812_gpio

#include <zephyr/drivers/led_strip.h>

#include <string.h>

#define LOG_LEVEL CONFIG_LED_STRIP_LOG_LEVEL
#include <zephyr/logging/log.h>
LOG_MODULE_REGISTER(ws2812_gpio);

#include <zephyr/kernel.h>
#include <soc.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/gpio.h>
#include <zephyr/device.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/clock_control.h>
#include <zephyr/drivers/clock_control/nrf_clock_control.h>
#include <zephyr/dt-bindings/led/led.h>

struct ws2812_gpio_cfg {
    struct gpio_dt_spec in_gpio;
    uint8_t num_colors;
    const uint8_t *color_mapping;
};

/*
 * T1H: 1 bit high pulse delay: 12 cycles == .75 usec
 * T0H: 0 bit high pulse delay: 4 cycles == .25 usec
 *
 * We can't use k_busy_wait() here: its argument is in microseconds,
 * and we need roughly .05 microsecond resolution.
 */
#define DELAY_T1H                                                                                  \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"

#define DELAY_T0H                                                                                  \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"                                       \
    "nop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\nnop\n"

/*
 * GPIO set/clear.
 *
 * We should be able to make this portable using the results of
 * https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/issues/11917.
 *
 * We already have the GPIO device stashed in ws2812_gpio_config, so
 * this driver can be used as a test case for the optimized API.
 *
 * Per Arm docs, both Rd and Rn must be r0-r7, so we use the "l"
 * constraint in the below assembly.
 */
#define SET_HIGH "str %[p], [%[s], #0]\n" /* OUTSET = BIT(LED_PIN) */
#define SET_LOW  "str %[p], [%[c], #0]\n" /* OUTCLR = BIT(LED_PIN) */

/* Send out a 1 bit's pulse */
#define ONE_BIT(set, clear, pin)                                                                   \
    __asm volatile(SET_HIGH DELAY_T1H SET_LOW DELAY_T0H ::[s] "l"(set), [c] "l"(clear),        \
               [p] "l"(pin));

/* Send out a 0 bit's pulse */
#define ZERO_BIT(set, clear, pin)                                                                  \
    __asm volatile(SET_HIGH DELAY_T0H SET_LOW DELAY_T1H ::[s] "l"(set), [c] "l"(clear),        \
               [p] "l"(pin));

/*
 * Latch current color values on strip and reset its state machines.
 */
static inline void ws2812_led_strip_reset_delay(uint16_t delay)
{
    k_usleep(delay);
}

static int send_buf(const struct device *dev, uint8_t *buf, size_t len)
{
    const struct ws2812_gpio_cfg *config = dev->config;
    volatile uint32_t *set = (uint32_t *)&NRF_P0->OUTSET;
    volatile uint32_t *clear = (uint32_t *)&NRF_P0->OUTCLR;
    const uint32_t pin = BIT(config->in_gpio.pin);
    unsigned int key;

    struct onoff_manager *mgr = z_nrf_clock_control_get_onoff(CLOCK_CONTROL_NRF_SUBSYS_HF);
    struct onoff_client cli;
    int rc;

    sys_notify_init_spinwait(&cli.notify);
    rc = onoff_request(mgr, &cli);
    if (rc < 0) {
        return rc;
    }

    while (sys_notify_fetch_result(&cli.notify, &rc)) {
        /* pend until clock is up and running */
    }

    size_t i;
    int j = 0;
    key = irq_lock();

    while (len--) {
        /*
         * Generate signal out of the bits, MSbit first.
         *
         * Accumulator maintenance and branching mean the
         * inter-bit time will be longer than TxL, but the
         * wp.josh.com blog post says we have at least 5 usec
         * of slack time between bits before we risk the
         * signal getting latched, so this will be fine as
         * long as the compiler does something minimally
         * reasonable.
         */
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (0b10000000 & (*(buf + j) << i)) {
                ONE_BIT(set, clear, pin);
            } else {
                ZERO_BIT(set, clear, pin);
            }
        }
        j++;
    }

    irq_unlock(key);

    rc = onoff_release(mgr);
    /* Returns non-negative value on success. Cap to 0 as API states. */
    rc = MIN(rc, 0);

    return rc;
}

It seems like a few extra clock cycles are spent on something when calling the "nop" delays for the first time. I'm not sure how to remove whatever is causing those wasted cycles though.
I haven't worked with assembly in C before so I'm not sure if the delay is coming from the RTOS or the assembler.

Since you have disabled interrupts the RTOS is not causing this issue.  Have you applied any optimisation?  What happens if you output a test pattern from a sequence of ONE_BIT/ ZERO_BIT calls without any of the loop overhead? *(buf + j) is loop invariant and should be evaluated outside the loop once, then assigned to a variable for use in the loop.

The initial delay may be loading the nop into instruction cache from memory?

You could access the cpu cycle counter. It's 1-2 instructions. Save the initial value and loop until the diff exceeds the desired delay https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0360/f/control-coprocessor-cp15/register-descriptions/c15--cycle-counter-register--ccnt-

You may also need a barrier instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491751/5382650

@CraigEstey got it right I think. Notice how both initial zero and initial one are bigger and the next ones are all the same. M33 has an I-cache; cache hit is 0-wait, cache miss is, well, not. So it is likely you are hitting cache-refill delays. I see two ways to deal with that: either get rid of the cache (disable/flush at each iteration) and hope for consistent flash delays; or warm up the cache somehow to get 0-wait code execution. I think but not sure it is a combined code/data cache so maybe just reading the code before its execution would be enough.

Did you consider to use some MCU module like PWM or UART to create consistent timing, instead a brittle software approach?

these are timing sensitive devices and painful at best with bit banging. this is why folks use the spi controller. to prime the cache try calling one bit and zero bit one or more times with a low level as the output. it wont help the other loops. for that you can rig up a short data set that is all zeros perhaps then run that. turning the cache off is a timing nightmare on top of the one you have already.

switching to the spi controller ideally with buffering or dma is your best bet and you dont have to disable interrupts. or use another tiny  mcu specific to creating this signal and use its spi controller and polling even plus uart to send the high level pattern over from the rtos. these devices are painful to use. pleasurable once you get the timing and protocol down

did you create this assembly solution? or did you find it somewhere and are trying to get it to work?

@thebusybee I need to control more individual strips than I have pwm or spi hardware for. Zephyr doesn't currently support runtime pinmuxing so this seemed like the easiest approach.

@old_timer I'm modifying existing code, but I did do research an the instructions are the same for my hardware. I did consider using a secondary mcu, but I don't want to add complexity/fault points to the system.

@AndreyTurkin I figured it probably had something to do loading from the cache. I tried to warm it up, by sending some data them waiting  for the duration of the reset delay, but that seemed to make the cache go cold again.
Is there a way I can force the cache to preload those assembly sequences?

@CraigEstey I believe the the Zephyr irq_lock() already implements a barrier, but I could be reading that wrong.
https://docs.zephyrproject.org/latest/kernel/services/interrupts.html#c.irq_lock

Barriers aren't "locklike". They're more like a speed bump. You need an isb as the last part of your nop sequence. Otherwise, because your loop decrement doesn't depend on the nop, you could fall through the loop before finishing all the nop instructions. This is due to superscalar architecture/pipelining and out-of-order execution. It explains why you get inconsistent timing on your loop iterations.

@CraigEstey I believe Cortex M33 is a in-order 3-stage (1-wide?) pipeline architecture. I don't think there is any trickery going on regarding nops in this one. Look at the oscillogram - second and following blips are roughly 25% duty as one would expect from the code. This suggests nops do take roughly the same time.

@Voxorin regarding the cache warming: @old_timer proposed a solution. More specifically, you might make the loop send 0x55 byte before the actual data. Furthermore, ONE_BIT and ZERO_BIT should receive clear as their first and second argument for that bogus byte. And the inner loop must be the same for all the bytes (preferably with no extra conditional pathways). This way the first bogus byte would warm the cache, and it wouldn't be seen on the physical pin. Notice this is an associative cache, so maybe it is possible to have a collision inside the loop itself - so not a sure solution.

@AndreyTurkin It is armv8-m which has an isb instruction. It won't hurt and will help. It implies that there is an instruction pipeline (of whatever depth). When I debug such arches (and I've done work on armv8 before), I add such stuff, get it working, and then "tweak" it. I'd add the isb (even if it doesn't do anything), leave it in until things are working. Then, we could try removing it ("tweaking"). Also, seriously, if I were doing this, I'd be doing the cvtvec_el0 loop rather than trying to get the "cute" nop sequence to work.

@AndreyTurkin I tried warming the cache as suggested, flushing it each loop, and even disabling both data and instruction caches with the Zephyr api. Nothing seems to make a difference.

@CraigEstey I tried adding data and/or instruction barriers both in and outside the loop using the Zephyr API. No change unfortunately. I guess I'll try using the cpu cycle counter next.

@Voxorin I would have done the cycle counter first ;-) BTW, it needs isb before the reading the cntvct_el0 register. It states this in the docs.

@Clifford I changed *(buf + j) back to *(buf++), assigned it to a variable before using it in the loop, and removed the variable j. No change. Removing the loop entirely and using a test pattern does give the expected timing though.

have you tried running from ram instead of flash?  does the flash have a prefetch buffer you can enable/disable?

It may also be better also to walk the mask and leave b alone: if((0x80 >> i) & b). However your test has disproven your "extra nop cycles" hypothesis I think.  Occam's razor would suggest the compiler generated code in any case.  Have you looked at the generated assembly?  You did not address my question about optimisation.

@Clifford I have optimizations set off at the KConfig level. I haven't looked at the generated assembly yet. I suppose I should've started there haha

Since your delays are many NOPs long, you could use short loops instead of NOPs to save code footprint.  The difference between cache hit and miss would be smaller since later iterations would hit in cache.  Craig's suggestion of reading the CPU cycle counters in a spin-wait loop is even better, though; worst case should be an extra couple cycles if the cycle-read instruction misses in cache.  Or extrapolate all future deadlines from one reference point instead of trying to do separate fixed-length delays between code that might have run at different speeds or even handled an IRQ.

I had the same problem on the nRF5340. I took the approach of disabling the instruction cache for the duration of the bit-banging.
On the nRF5340 this can be achieved by writing 0 to the CACHE.ENABLE register before the transaction and then restoring it to it's original state after. This looks like the following modification:
// Disable CACHE.ENABLE to ensure clean timing including for first pulse
volatile uint32_t* icachecnf = (uint32_t*)(0x50001000 + 0x500);
uint32_t old = *icachecnf;
*icachecnf = 0;

while (len--) {
    // omitted for brevity...
}

*icachecnf = old;

After doing this I needed to adjust timing configurations by looking at the waveform with a scope and linearly adjusting them to the right lengths. For me on a nRF5340 at 128MHz that resulted in:
CONFIG_DELAY_T0H=41
CONFIG_DELAY_T0L=48
CONFIG_DELAY_T1H=87
CONFIG_DELAY_T1L=46

You will need to find the equivalent register for your uC and do the timing measurements. Looking briefly at the product sheet for the nRF9160 it looks like NVMC.ICACHECNF may do this for that part, which means replacing 0x50001000 + 0x500 with 0x50039000 + 0x540. (I don't have a nRF9160 so I can't test this, and also note that this will be different if you're running in nonsecure mode -- see the product specification.)
